# No module named 'igraph._igraph'

Tags: python, python-3.x, igraph

I just installed python-igraph 0.7.1 from source with no problems. I didn't already have the C library installed because using the repository version caused errors while building, but setup.py successfully compiled it.

However, now I can't import it. I get the following error:

```
>>> import igraph
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/jeffcollins/Downloads/python-igraph-0.7.1/igraph/__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from igraph._igraph import *
ImportError: No module named 'igraph._igraph'
```

Prior to my upgrade from trusty to vivid I didn't have this problem, but my install on trusty was long enough ago that I don't remember if anything else relevant has changed (not the Python or python-igraph versions, though).

My system info, if relevant:

- Samsung Chromebook 2
- ARMv7 Processor rev 3 (v7l) x4
- Ubuntu 15.04 (via crouton)
- Python 3.4.3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This usually happens when you are standing right in the folder where you extracted the source tree to. The source tree contains a folder named `igraph`, but there is no `_igraph.so` within it - `_igraph.so` is created in some subfolder of `build` when you build igraph. When you type `import igraph`, Python thinks that you meant the `igraph` folder relative to the current folder, not the `igraph` package that you have just installed.

Solution: change to another directory that does not have a subfolder named `igraph`, and try again.

Comment: I'm getting the same error and my folder structure is: /home/debvrat/research/package_storage/igraph/lib/python3.6/site-packages/igraph/__init__.py

The issue is, other users having access to the same folder are able to run the package smoothly. But I'm getting ImportError: No module named 'igraph._igraph'.

What could be going wrong? The subfolder issue does not seem to crop up for other users.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might not be python 3.4.3 maybe. Just a thought, since I've tried tons of websites for this on a chromebook. If you could tell me where you downloaded it from, that would help me a lot. :)

Comment: No, it worked just fine with Tamás's solution. Compiling it by running setup.py with the 3.4.3 interpreter should get you a 3.4.3 version of igraph.