# Error while importing igraph

Tags: python, igraph, python-wheel

I am using Python 3.6 on Windows 7 and I have a problem with the `igraph` package. I was having errors while I was trying to install it using `pip`, so I decided to install it from the `.whl` file. Unfortunately, I couldn't find version appropriate for Python 3.6, so I downloaded another version and changed the name of the file so that it looked like it was designed for Python 3.6. The installation was **successful**, but when I am trying to run a script which uses the `igraph` module - a following error message appears:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Jarek/Documents/Studia/Programowanie/Python na studiach/Analysis of Unstructured Data/List2.py", line 6, in <module>
    import igraph as ig
  File "C:\Users\Jarek\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\igraph\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from igraph._igraph import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'igraph._igraph'
```

I haw a very similar issue under [Python igraph import error on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39872099/python-igraph-import-error-on-windows)
but there was no answer there. I have also seen 
[No module named 'igraph._igraph'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32342541/no-module-named-igraph-igraph) but suggestion given there does not help me (or I do not know how to properly apply it).

Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> I couldn't find version appropriate for Python 3.6, so I downloaded another version and changed the name of the file so that it looked like it was designed for Python 3.6.

So the trick didn't work. Use Python 2.6 or 2.7. Or compile from sources.